# Jenkins Build - Can't find Java class

Tags: java, database, oracle, maven, jenkins

I have maven project I want to build through Jenkins. I added an ojdbc standalone JAR to the classpath, to access a database. But when Jenkins tries to load the OracleDriver, it can't find it. Local build works perfect though.

Do I have to integrate the OracleDriver through maven? I just load the driver like that:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASS);
```

Jenkins error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`

Comment: Can you please share the dependencies section of your pom?

Comment: are you build local build via eclipse or maven . and in case maven then how is OracleDriver declared in it ?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working. I just had to install the ojdbc.jar via maven. I followed this guide: http://javabycode.com/build-tools/maven/add-oracle-jdbc-driver-maven.html